# Application with maps for Android: General Strategy

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

Before developing an application I researched what solutions might apply while creating lightweight application with maps for Android.

*Basic usage of app is while hiking* and therefore below are **requirements app must meet**:

1. Must be using hardware resources as few as possible.
2. Must have ability to save map data for further offline usage for selected local area.
3. Must have ability to load custom data generated by 3dparity like kml files and custom markers.

**Application basic flow** is:

Some site community contributes custom markers and kml (or other layer data type) files for desired region.

Application combines some map provider map (like Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps) + Community data for desired region and gives offline usage ability to users. Where users can prepare map with internet connection before hiking and use it offline while hiking.

**Strategy and primary problems to solve:**

1. Choose lightweight map sdk.
2. Solve offline maps problem.

**Choosing lightweight maps sdk and problems related to it:**

While hiking people often use older versions of smartphones which drain less battery power because they come with older version of Android therefore apps for older versions of android use less computing power.

Common solution here is Google Maps SDK 2.0 which by itself is provided by Google Play SDK but Google Play SDK is getting heavier over time and it requires that user had installed almost later version of Google Play Services as I guess.

Pros of Google Maps SDK 2.0 is that it provides great codebase for further extension and also a great MapView component ready with all UI tweaks.

Cons of Google Maps SDK 2.0 is that it requires user to have Google Play Services installed which by itself drains phone charge. Also new MapView UI components might require more computing resources.

**Solving offline maps problem**:

As I researched it is possible to provide custom tiles stored anywhere on device in Google Maps SDK 2.0 using **TileProvider** interface which gives great controls over tiles.  Main abstract method of it is:

```
public Tile (int width, int height, byte[] data).
```

Other SDKs:

MapBox android sdk comes closer to Google Maps SDK 2.0. It is promissing but is still beta and is opensource. Compared to other less known android map sdks MapBox has gentle documentation, nice tools, is almost lightweight and has community but comes with still bugs.

Also I tried an app by my opinion developed using Google Maps SDK 2.0 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vecturagames.android.app.gpxviewer

In my best guesses this app is using Google Maps SDK MapView to display maps from various sources like OpenStreetMap, MapBox and from almost every map provider available online including google.

**Questions:**

1. What are your best practices for developing lightweight apps for android with maps and offline tile base support?
2. Is it possible avoid Google Play Services dependency while using Google Maps SDK 2.0?
3. Are there any other opensource map sdks which are performance friendly? For example using OpenStreetMaps map base.